# php __FILE__ not working

Tags: php, include, require, dirname

I am trying to load a php file B.PHP from another php file A.PHP, plus I want to send a variable via $_GET. Both files are stored on the same directory. I tried several ways:

1st)
Directly write on my file:

```
require (__FILE__)."\b.php?action=1";
```

The result of doing an echo is: C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\a.phpb.php?action=1, so INCORRECT!

So then I tried:

```
require (__FILE__)."\..\b.php?action=1"; INCORRECT again
```

2nd)
On a different PHP I set:

```
define('MAINDIR',dirname(__FILE__) . '\\');
define('DL_DIR',MAINDIR . 'pfc\\html\\');   // Also tried with a normal '/'
```

And then on my file I just do:

```
require DL_DIR."b.php?action=1";  I also tried with include, but I guess this has nothing to do.
```

In this case, if I do an echo I get: C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\b.php, so CORRECT!

However, when I run my program, I get the next error:

**Warning**: require (C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\b.php?action=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\a.php on line 101

**Warning**: require (): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\b.php?action=1' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\a.php on line 101

OBVIOUSLY it cannot find a file inside a file. So I tried again the '..\' wih this version... WRONG!

3rd) Adding realpath to the equation

```
require realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."\b.php?action=1");
```

And, again, I get:

**Warning**: require (): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\HTML_menu_supervisor.php on line 101

**Warning**: require (): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\HTML_menu_supervisor.php on line 101

I really don't know what is going on. Please someone help me! And thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Can you try to include file without using any global variable and try to see whether it does the job or not.

Comment: You cannot pass variables in an include/require statement as `GET` parameters, it just doesn't work like that. And `__FILE__` is also obviously not working like that. A simple `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../b.php` should do the trick though. Although as your on windows, you might need to use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `/`.

Comment: without global variable it works just fine. I can even set the variable with $_GET and then call the other file with no variables on it and get those variables later on from it. However I cant use this method for my purpose

Comment: @nietonfir Doing an echo of your trick (and adding the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) just gives: C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc\html\..\b.php?action=1, so invalid link

Comment: Side note of possible interest: as of PHP 5.3, [`__DIR__` is available](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), which is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't pass parameters via `require` or `include`. Therefore I believe that your `require`s are actually looking for a file that doesn't exists (since you probably don't have a file named `b.php?action=1`.

You can just set whatever variable(s) you need to and reference them in the `require`d files (assuming they're in the same scope).

Comment: I know. However the manual gives this example:

    // Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the local filesystem.
    include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';    

    // Works.
    include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

So I was trying to find the way of writing the absolute path.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user2612097 So you're expecting what the manual explicitly states "Won't work" to work?

Comment: From the same link: "Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled." Even not on Windows this would be bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: You explicitly cannot do this (in Windows) and there is an alternate acceptable (and preferable) way to do this anyhow, which I've stated above.

Comment: @Wiseguy it says "wont work" for a relative path, but "works" for a complete url..that's the point

Comment: @user2612097 "Example #3 include through HTTP" It's talking about URLs, as you said, but not local files.

Comment: @user2612097 Just let go :) ... You can include a file by file name. So you cannot put in any 'querystring' there. And (most times) you can include a file by URL. And *only* then you can put in a 'querystring'. Furthermore, you don't *need* to pass anything along, as the included file will always have all variables accessible to it that the calling file already had.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get parameters to your include.

if you url looks something like this

```
localhost/myfunction.php?action=1
```

myfunction.php:

```
    require (__DIR__)."\..\b.php";
```

You could include your file and it will get the GET variable out of the box.

An include is a copy&paste of your included file .

So your `b.php` should look like this:

```
$allowedGetValues = array(1,2,3,4);


if(isset($_GET['action']) && array_key_exists($_GET['action'],$allowedGetValues) ){
    .. 
}
```

Comment: He's on windows and passing parameters via require or include isn't supported as per the documentation.

Comment: where have i written that there is a parameter in the include or require? if i include a file, than the GET parameter in my url would also be available in the b.php

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I thought it was there before. Make a small edit to your answer and I should be able to un-downvote.

Comment: If one of the answer's helped you, so mark it. That the answer will pushed to the top and will be faster noticed for other person with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use include or require function like below -

```
include('b.php');
or
require('b.php');
```